# Factor ring is a field and finding its characteristic

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, gaussian-integers

Let $E = \mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ where $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ denotes the ring of Gaussian integers and $I=\langle 2-i \rangle$, an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

We need to prove that $E$ is a field and then go on to determine the characteristic of the field.

To prove it is a field, I think the best route is to simply show that it satisfies the definition of a field. As for the characteristic, I am not really sure where to go from here. Does anyone have any suggestions for this? Thanks!

Comment: For coprime $a,b$ we have $\mathbb Z[i]/(a - ib) \cong \mathbb Z/(a^2 + b^2).$ So we obtain the finite field $\Bbb F_5$, see the duplicate below. For a maximal ideal $I$ in $R=\Bbb Z[i]$, the quotient is always a field.

Comment: Great, I've got that now. However, I'm struggling to prove the quotient ring is a field. A field is a commutative ring with unity and every non zero element has an inverse. Commutativity is easy to see and we have unity $1+\langle2-i\rangle$. I'm struggling to prove the inverse requirement. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to use a different fact from abstract algebra (see above): $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is maximal. Then you have the inverse for free.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :)